# Wordpress mobile and desktop header problems

Tags: headers

the thing is that in mobile/tabler versions blank white space appears. In desktop version there is no such problem. Moreover, I noticed that if you drag something in mobile version from that blank space, it appears to be a logo from header.
I would appreciate any help. 
My website: www.avizen.lt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem either in your theme setting or in css. if the theme setting 
try make header backround #000 on mobile and align logo center.

So that will how your site look on mobile

[image]

if you write custom css, here is the solution

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #masthead_TesseractTheme .site-branding {
       text-align: center !important;
    }
    #masthead_TesseractTheme {
       background: #000 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for all the pages except 'About' page. White space still appears. How can I solve that? And the second question is how can I adjust the size of my logo in mobile/tablet versions?

Comment: i have check in all the pages, still same issue. you will have to check the theme setting first. either in your theme files or theme site, there must be online documentation about your theme. if this cant solve your issue, go to your theme css http://www.avizen.lt/wp-content/themes/TESSERACT/css/site-banner.css then line 874 remove #masthead_TesseractTheme{ background:#FFF !important;}

Comment: I tried to post your before given css code and that worked for all pages! Thank you

Comment: Maybe you know how can I adjust size of my logo in mobile/tablet version?

Comment: in the same media try increase the size of logo using css. #site-banner .site-logo img { height: 70px;} let me know if this help. try vote up and accept the answer if this solve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the element with the id 'site-banner' for smaller screens (mobile/tablet) by adding the 'display: none;' css rule to the following file 'site-banner.css' at line 432:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
#site-banner {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: none;
}
```